# VS 2015 std::char_traits<char16_t> operations

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, i18n, unicode

At my workplace, we changed string type (which holds internationalized characters) for from `std::wstring` to `std::u16string` after VS 2015(Update 3) compiler upgrade.

Due to this, we are seeing loads of performance regressions such as [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3130786/std-u16string-copying-performance-much-worse-than-std-wstring).

The profiler analysis reveals that `std::u16string`'s `std::char_traits<char16_t>` operations such as `copy`, `compare`, `find` and `assign` are the most hit and are taking longer than `std::wstring`'s `std::char_traits<wchar_t>` counterparts.

These `std::char_traits<wchar_t>` operations are written in terms of `std::wmem*` and `std::char_traits<char16_t>` operations are written in terms of `for loops`.

If we change these traits operations for `char16_t` type (or `std::u16string`) to use our own customized traits, we are seeing performance improvements with performance comparable to `std::wstring`.

We are planning to write our own custom traits (until MS fixes it for next version of VS) as follows

```
struct string_custom_traits : public std::char_traits<char16_t>
{
    static const char16_t * copy(char16_t* dest, const char16_t* src, size_t count)
    {
        return (count == 0 ? src : (char16_t*)std::memcpy(dest, src, count * sizeof(char16_t)));
    }

 };
```

Would that be OK? Are there any problems with this approach ?

Comment: Interesting. Should by `I10n` not `i18n` as the internationalization part is about translating the strings in different languages. The localization part is writing the code in such a way that it can be internationalized.

Comment: @LokiAstari Why delete the answer you posted ? I was about to accept it...

Comment: Because a comment by @Martin R make me uncertain I was correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing in `std::char_traits::copy` says to return `src` when `count` is zero.  Further, we must return a pointer to *modifiable* `char_type`, which also precludes returning `src`.

So I think we should write:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

struct string_custom_traits : public std::char_traits<char16_t>
{
    static char_type * copy(char_type* dest, const char_type* src, size_t count)
    {
        return (char_type*)std::memcpy(dest, src, count * sizeof *src);
    }

    static char_type *move(char_type* dest, const char_type* src, size_t count)
    {
        return (char_type*)std::memmove(dest, src, count * sizeof *src);
    }
};
```

I've used the template-provided alias `char_type` for consistency and in case you want to turn this traits class into a template itself.

Make sure you understand and accept the differences between UCS-2 and UTF-16 if you handle characters outside the BMP.

Comment: Well, using `std::copy_n` is a bit more C++-y, and avoids the need for casting and such.

Comment: Good point - I followed the question's lead (with the ugly cast) instead of thinking from scratch.  `std::copy_n` is a bit more tricky, as it has undefined behaviour if source and destination overlap.  Fixing that might reintroduce the performance problems that motivated the code in the first place!

Comment: Well, the behavior is expected to be UB in that case, so nothing lost.